# How to create a 2D array inside a 'for' loop in matlab

Tags: arrays, matlab

I am new to matlab and I am trying to calculate ifft transform of vector Y for z=1:100.

Here is the current version of the relevant part of the code (no array):

```
for z=1:100
Y=(exp(kx.^2))*(exp(i*z/2*k0)).*PSIX_0;
psix_z=ifft(Y);
end
```

where:
PSIX_0 and kx are both 1x100 arays.
k0 is a constant.

All I can see now is the last row for z=100. Is there a way to recive a ifft of vector Y for each value of z?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

How about `psix_z(z,:) = ifft(Y);`?  Or `psix_z(:,z)`, depending on whether the `ifft` is a row or column vector.